# Restricted shell within docker container

Tags: docker, chroot, limit, pty, jails

Some context for my question: I am working on a pty NodeJS server running in docker where I want to provide users connecting to the shell an isolated environment where they can play around with commands without affecting any other users connected to the docker container.

I have looked into cgroups, namespaces, jailkit and chroot but not sure where to start. There is a site called tutorialspoint which provides a bash playground and this is pretty much what I am trying to achieve https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php

So in conclusion I want to run a docker container where I can easily spawn new shells for any amount of users. The shells should be restricted to having only write access in the users home folder and I want to limit the commands a user can run. In the world of Unix, what would I use to achieve this?

Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT: One thing that confused me is that if I run the following commands in the bash playground on tutorialspoint:

```bsh
id
cat /etc/passwd
```

I do not see the current user in the passwd list. Why is it that the passwd on tutorialspoint does not include the connected users? How does that work together with the Unix permission model?

Comment: Technically it would be a lot simpler/safer to spawn a container per user. Containers are not VMs, they are mere processes.

Comment: @xenoid Thank you, I think this is where I am heading. I just tried starting a container as a different user `docker run --rm -it --name test --user 1000 debian bash` and It's close to what I am looking for

Comment: and for an extra level of isolation from the host, you might want to run docker in a VM.  To affect the host, an attacker would first have to break out of the docker container, and then break out of the VM.

Comment: And in particular containers **already use** namespaces and chroot, so they do exactly what you want out of the box.

Comment: @joakim hanson, better not use 1000 as the user id for the container,this is likely and id that already exists. Create an id specifically to run these containers.

Comment: @xenoid I found something called gotty which seems to work nicely with the idea I had. I’ll simply add new pods in my kubernetes cluster which will also run gotty to expose a TTY that I can connect to from xterm.js. I will add a comment to the post when I’ve reached what I want. Thanks for the help!